# When building a Rust binary with lto=true, is there a way to limit the crates the linker examines?

Tags: rust, linker

The program I have ends up using over 110 `crates` in its build. However, the core performance gains (where 80+%) of the benefit is, resides in only a few 'crates'. Ya, I took the time to drill down through crates that used crates. Consequently, I'd like the `linker` to use `lto` options for only those 5-6 `crates`, rather that looking at all +110. Does anyone know if this is possible? And, if it is, how do I direct the `linker` to do it? Yes, the difference is just build-time, but its only going to get worse as I add more `crates`.

Comment: you might want to try [lto="thin"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#lto)